# Composite view failing to render in Eclipse in edit mode

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout

I'm trying to build a widget that is composed of a few controls grouped together. Here's the widget:

```
public class VarioView extends RelativeLayout {

private int value;
private ImageView m_circle;
private TextView m_varioText;
private TextView m_units;
public VarioView(Context context)
{
    this(context,null);
}
public VarioView(Context context, AttributeSet attr)
{
    this(context,attr, 0);
}
public VarioView(Context context, AttributeSet attr, int defStyle)
{
    super(context, attr, defStyle);
    //View.inflate(context, R.layout.vario, this);
    LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    li.inflate(R.layout.vario, this, true);

    m_circle = (ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.VarioCircle);
    m_varioText = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.VarioText);

    //m_circle.setColorFilter(Color.BLUE);
}
public int getValue() {
    return value;
}
public void setValue(int value) {
    m_varioText.setText(Integer.valueOf(value).toString());
    this.value = value;
}
}
```

Here's the widget xml

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
 >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/VarioCircle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:contentDescription="Vario Circle"
        android:src="@drawable/circle3" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/VarioText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="200"
        android:textColor="#FF0000"
        android:textSize="60sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="monospace" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/VarioUnits"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/VarioText"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:text="fpm"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
</RelativeLayout>

</merge>
```

Here's circle shape:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval"
    android:useLevel="false"
    android:color="#FF0000" >

    <size
    android:height="200dip"
    android:width="200dip" />

    <stroke
    android:width="10dp"
    android:color="#FF0000" />

</shape>
```

And in my main view I'm just using it like this:

```
 <com.proflite.VarioView

         android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
 />
```

My problem is that it works fine when I run it in emulator (or real device), but when I try to go to graphical editor in Eclipse it draws a grey box over the control and gives me this:

```
The following classes could not be instantiated:
- com.proflite.VarioView (Open Class, Show Error Log)
See the Error Log (Window > Show View) for more details.
Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom views to skip code when shown in Eclipse

android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Could not resolve resource value: 0x7F030001.
    at android.content.res.BridgeResources.throwException(BridgeResources.java:693)
    at android.content.res.BridgeResources.getLayout(BridgeResources.java:271)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:394)
    at com.proflite.VarioView.<init>(VarioView.java:30)
    at com.proflite.VarioView.<init>(VarioView.java:23)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.ProjectCallback.instantiateClass(ProjectCallback.java:413)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.ProjectCallback.loadView(ProjectCallback.java:170)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:207)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:135)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:746)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:718)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:372)
```

Extra info, I check `0x7F030001` is mapped to `R.layout.vario` and the error is coming out of this line: `li.inflate(R.layout.vario, this, true);`. Additionally if I change it to `li.inflate(R.layout.vario, this);` it doesn't give the error, but the control just shows "blank", doesn't render in editmode (still works when actually run).

I would REALLY like to be able to visualize the layout in the editor cuz it takes a long time to make minor layout alterations and rerun them in emulator.

Thanks

** Note ** the error comes from the layout where the control is placed. It actually renders successfully if I do graphical edit on the control itself.

Comment: I do not get the error in the graphical layout with your code. Though I had to change `@drawable/circle3` to something else, so maybe there is the problem.

Comment: Did you try the actual layout that uses the VarioView or did you just check the vario.xml in graphical editor. It works fine for me if I view the actual composite control layout graphical editor, but fails if I try to use it by placing it on another layout. If it actually works for you as placed can you please upload a project file somewhere so I can check.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, I feel pretty stupid. Everything worked after I restarted Eclipse.

Comment: Same situation and same solution. Waist 1 hour and find you answer.